# VB Scripting to excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am a help desk technical at my company and I am trying to create a vb login script that would gather various things about the user and computer and create or amend a excel spread sheet on a network drive. A little about my background with programming, I am not a programmer.  My knowledge is limited but I do understand some programming logic. So far I have been able to Frankenstein together this vbs script from various sources online with even some of my very own programming.  Here is my snag.  I want to list all of the network drives of an user to a single cell within excel.  I've tried everything with no success.
The closest I can get is it listing just one (the last) network drive.  The other issue I've been having is that it will not list any of my member of groups from AD.  I know I am a super novice but I am willing to learn and understand.  Any help would be great!
Here is my code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set env = oShell.environment("Process")
strComputer = env.Item("Computername")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objExcel.worksheets(2).delete
objExcel.worksheets(2).delete
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = OutputFile
strOut = ""
getOSInfo

Sub getOSInfo()
    On Error Resume Next

    objExcel.worksheets(1).Activate
    objExcel.worksheets(1).Name = "Computer Info"
    objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Computer Name"
    objExcel.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Computer Name from system"
    objExcel.Cells(3, 1).Value = "IP(s) from system"
    objExcel.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Logon Name"   
    objExcel.Cells(5, 1).Value = "Operating System"
    objExcel.Cells(6, 1).Value = "Last Bootup Time"
    objExcel.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Install Date"
    objExcel.Cells(8, 1).Value = "Manufacturer"
    objExcel.Cells(9, 1).Value = "Serial Number"
    objExcel.Cells(10, 1).Value = "Model"
    objExcel.Cells(11, 1).Value = "Mapped Drives"
    objExcel.Cells(12, 1).Value = "Member of Group(s)"
    objExcel.Cells(13, 1).Value = "Amt. of Storage Allocated"
    objExcel.Cells(14, 1).Value = "# of Processors"
    objExcel.Cells(15, 1).Value = "Processor Type"
    objExcel.Cells(16, 1).Value = "Memory (GB)"
    colVar=2

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objExcel.Cells(1, colVar).Value = strComputer
        objExcel.Cells(2, colVar).Value = "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description
        printout "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description
        colVar = colVar+1
        Err.Clear
    Else

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_OperatingSystem for " & strComputer
        Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_BIOS for " & strComputer
        Set colBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_ComputerSystem for " & strComputer
        Set colComputerSystem = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration for " & strComputer
        Set colNetworkAdapterConfiguration = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_MappedLogicalDisk for " & strComputer               
        Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting Win32_Processor info for " & strComputer
        Set colProc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

        For Each objOS In colOperatingSystems

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting Computer Name for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(1, colVar).Value = strComputer

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting Last Boot Time for " & strComputer
            Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
            dtmConvertedDate.Value = objOS.InstallDate
            dtmInstallDate = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
            objExcel.Cells(7, colVar).Value = dtmInstallDate
            tempArray = Split(objOS.name, "|")
            objExcel.Cells(6, colVar).Value = tempArray(0)
            dtmConvertedDate.Value = objOS.LastBootUpTime
            dtmBootTime = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
            objExcel.Cells(5, colVar).Value = dtmBootTime
        Next

        For Each objBIOS In colBIOS
            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting BIOS info for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(9, colVar).Value = objBIOS.SerialNumber
        Next

        For Each objCS In colComputerSystem

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting Manufacturer info for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(8, colVar).Value = objCS.Manufacturer

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting Model info for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(10, colVar).Value = objCS.Model

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting name from WMI for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(2, colVar).Value = objCS.name

            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting Total Physical Memory for " & strComputer
            objExcel.Cells(16, colVar).Value = Round(objCS.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024/1024/1024,2)
        Next

        For Each objNetAdapter In colNetworkAdapterConfiguration
            objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting IP Addresses for " & strComputer
            ipAddress = objNetAdapter.ipaddress
            For i = 0 To UBound(ipaddress)
                If iplist = "" Then
                    iplist = ipaddress(i)
                Else
                    iplist = iplist & ", " & ipaddress(i)
                End If
            Next
            objExcel.Cells(3, colVar).Value = iplist

        Next

        Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
        For i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2
        objExcel.Cells(11, colVar).Value = colDrives.Item(i) & vbTab & colDrives.Item (i + 1)
        Next

        Err.Clear
        strUser = strComputer & "$"
        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Getting AD Group info for " & strComputer
        Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
        defaultNC = objRoot.Get("defaultnamingcontext")
        computerDN = FindUser(strUser, defaultNC)
        ouarray = Split(computerDN,",")
        For i = 1 To UBound(ouarray)
            If ou = "" Then
                ou = ouarray(i)
            Else
                ou = ou & "," & ouarray(i)
            End If
        Next

        Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colItems = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
        For Each objItem In colItems
            strUsers = objItem.UserName
        Next 

        objExcel.Cells(4, colVar).Value = strUsers 'ou

        Set dicSeenGroup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        strGroups = DisplayGroups(computerDN,"",dicSeenGroup)
        aryGroups = Split(strGroups,"CN=")
        strGroups = ""
        For i = 2 To UBound(aryGroups)
            strGroups = strGroups & ", " & aryGroups(i)
        Next
        objExcel.Cells(12, colVar).Value = Right(strGroups,Len(strGroups) -2)
        Err.Clear

        stroutput = getDriveLettersAndSize(strComputer)
        objExcel.Cells(13, colVar).Value = Left(stroutput,Len(stroutput)-2)

        ProcCount = 0
        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Setting number of processors for " & strComputer
        For Each processor In colProc
            ProcCount = ProcCount + 1
            ProcName = processor.name
        Next
        objExcel.Cells(14, colVar).Value = ProcCount
        objExcel.Cells(15, colVar).Value = Trim(ProcName)

        strOut = ""
        iplist = ""
        ou = ""
        colVar = colVar+1
    End If

    objExcel.Cells.Select
    objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    objExcel.Range("B2").Select
    objExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    objWorksheet.Columns("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = -4131
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Finished gathering computer info"

End Sub

Function FindUser(Byval UserName, Byval Domain)
    On Error Resume Next

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

    cmd.activeconnection=cn
    cmd.commandtext="SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://" & Domain & "' WHERE sAMAccountName = '" & UserName & "'"

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    If Err<>0 Then
        FindUser="Error connecting to Active Directory Database:" & Err.description
        'wscript.quit
    Else
        If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            FindUser = rs(0)
        Else
            FindUser = "Not Found"
        End If
    End If
    cn.close
End Function

Function DisplayGroups ( strObjectADsPath, strSpaces, dicSeenGroup)
    Set objObject = GetObject(strObjectADsPath)
    'strOut must be global variable
    strOut = strOut & strSpaces & objObject.Name
    On Error Resume Next ' Doing this to avoid an error when memberOf is empty
    If IsArray( objObject.Get("memberOf") ) Then
        colGroups = objObject.Get("memberOf")
    Else
        colGroups = Array( objObject.Get("memberOf") )
    End If

    For Each strGroupDN In colGroups
        If Not dicSeenGroup.Exists(strGroupDN) Then
            dicSeenGroup.Add strGroupDN, 1
            DisplayGroups "LDAP://" & strGroupDN, strSpaces & " ", dicSeenGroup
        End If
    Next
    Err.Clear
    DisplayGroups = strOut
End Function

Function getDriveLettersAndSize(strComputer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2")
    If Err.Number Then
        getDriveLettersAndSize = "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description & "  "
        Err.Clear
    Else
        On Error Goto 0
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3", , 48)
        For Each objItem In colItems
            getDriveLettersAndSize = getDriveLettersAndSize & objItem.Name & " " & Round(getDriveSizeTotal(strComputer,objItem.Name)/1024/1024/1024,2) & "GB, "
        Next
    End If
End Function

Function getDriveSizeTotal(strComputer, drvLetter)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2")
    strTemp = strComputer
    If Err.Number Then
        getDriveSizeTotal = "0"
        Err.Clear
    Else
        On Error Goto 0
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3", , 48)
        For Each objItem In colItems
            If UCase(objItem.Name) = UCase(drvLetter) Then
                getDriveSizeTotal = objItem.Size
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: First step to troubleshooting VBScript: remove `On Error Resume Next` and find out what actual error you get. Also, explain what you have tried exactly and how the results were different from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't intend to work through your code so I shall concentrate on the question:

> I want to list all of the network drives of an user to a single cell
>   within excel.

You would use string concatenation with the ampersand & operator:

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value & " " & "C:"
```

Replace "C:" with whatever variable contains the current drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the drives problem (without a leading blank):

```
>> Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
>> Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
>> sDrives = ""
>> For i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2
>>     sDrives = sDrives & vbTab & colDrives.Item(i)
>> Next
>> sDrives = Mid(sDrives, 2)
>> WScript.Echo """" & sDrives & """"
```

Put sDrives into the cell (once).